# Google App Engine and HTTPS Strategy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, gwt, ssl

I am designing my first GAE app and obviously need to use HTTPS for the login functionality (can't be sending my User's UIDs and passwords in cleartext!).

But I'm confused/nervous about how to handle requests after the initial login. The way I see it, I have 2 strategies:

- Use HTTPS for everything
- Switch back from HTTPS (for login) to plain ole' HTTP

The first option is more secure, but might introduce performance overhead (?) and possibly send my service bill through the roof. The second option is quicker and easier, but less secure.

The other factor here is that this would be a "single-page app" (using GWT), and certain sections of the UI will be able to accept payment and will require the secure transmission of financial data. So some AJAX requests *could* be HTTP, but others *must* be HTTPS.

So I ask:

- GAE has a nifty table explaining incoming/outgoing bandwidth resources, but never concretely defines how much I/O bandwidth can be dedicated for HTTPS. Does anybody know the restrictions here? I'm planning on using "Billing Enabled" and paying a little bit for the app (and for higher resource limits).
- Is it possible to have a GWT/single-page app where some portions of the UI use HTTP while others utilize HTTPS? Or is it "all or nothing"?
- Is there any *real* performance overheard to utilizing an all-HTTPS strategy?

Understanding these will help me decide between a HTTP/S hybrid solution, or a pure HTTPS solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start mixing http and https request you are as secure as you would be using http, because any http request can be intercepted and can introduce possible XSS attacks.

If you are serious about your security read up on it, assuming that you only require https for sensible data and transmitting the rest with http will bring you in a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Kurka (+1) - one thing though. I notice that GMail uses HTTPS for logins and then reverts back to HTTP (this is what gave me this idea in the first place!) Is there any particular reason why GMail can behave this way, but not a "normal" app? Thanks again!

Comment: well my gmail account does not do that, but I think I have seen that kind of behavior which is very easy to attack

Answer (score 1):

[You pay for http and https](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) the same for incoming bandwidth and you should see any difference in instances hours. The only difference is the [one time pay](https://www.globalsign.com/blog/ssl-with-google-app-engine.html) (per month) that you need to pay for SNI or VIP

Comment: Thanks @ShayErlichmen (+1) - can you please confirm that you meant to say "You pay for http and https the same for incoming bandwidth and you should **not** see any difference..."? Just want to confirm HTTPS won't change instance hours or bandiwdth utilization. Thanks again!

Comment: @pnongrata AFAIK (and saw) no, same instance hours same utilization.